# What's the most efficient way to create a dictionary using regex to distribute values to keys?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a list of values, and an dictionary association of regex to key name

```
{/regex1/: k, /regex2/: k2}
```

I need to distribute the values according to the regex and construct one dictionary with

```
{k: [v0, v1, ...], k2: [v01, v02, ...]}
```

where values := `[v0, v1, v01, v02, ...]` and `v0, v1, ...` are values that match regex1, and `v01, v02, ....` match regex2.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think a regexp can be used as the keys in objects, keys have to be strings.

Comment: It seems to me regular expressions can be strings.  In C++, we'd use a hash or a map.  I don't know what you use in JS.  Somebody seemed quick on the downvote, IMHO.

Comment: The regex i refer to is actually just a string, I will convert it on-the-fly to a regex when I'm actualy using it to pattern match values

Answer (score 0):

The keys of an object should be strings, not regexps. You can use `new RegExp()` to convert a string to the corresponding regexp. Or you could do the mapping the other way, from key names to regexp:

```
var dictionary = {k: /regexp1/, k2: /regexp2/};
```

Then you can use a nested loop, testing the values against each regexp.

```
result = {};
Object.entries(dictionary).forEach(([key, re]) => result[key] = values.filter(val => re.test(val)));
```

If you really want to use the regexp as the key it becomes:

```
var dictionary = {"regexp1": "k", "regexp2": "k2"};
Object.entries(dictionary).forEach(([reString, key]) => {
    var re = new RegExp(reString);
    result[key] = values.filter(val => re.test(val));
});
```